# Operaciones matematicas en ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como puedo hacer operaciones en los campos de mi formulario, es decir, 
tengo mi campo :

```
<%= f.input :cantidad %>
```

Que lo quiero multiplicar por :

```
<%= f.input :valor_unitario %>
```

Para que así mi campo de `valor_total`, tenga un valor por defecto que sería la operación de esos dos, supongo que tengo que hacerlo en el modelo, porque en la vista directamente es una mala practica, la verdad he intentado con:

```
def valor_total
  "#{cantidad}*#{valor_unitario}"
end
```

Pero me sale solo el texto, entonces supongo que estoy equivocado, también intento con:

```
def valor_total
  self.cantidad * self.valor_unitario
end
```

Pero tampoco funciona.

modelo:

```
class Atriremi < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :remision

  def valor_total
    self.cantidad * self.valor_unitario
  end
end
```

No tengo controlador ya que es un modelo independiente que hace parte de maestro de detalles creado con la gema *Cocoon*.

Controller remisiones

```
class RemisionsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @remisions = Remision.all
    end

    def show
      @remision = Remision.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json
        format.pdf do
            render template: "remisions/pdfRemi", pdf: 'pdfRemi'
        end
      end
    end

    def new
      @remision = Remision.new
    end

    def edit
      @remision = Remision.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      @remision = Remision.new(remision_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @remision.save
          format.html { redirect_to @remision, notice: 'Remision creada correctamente.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @remision }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @remision.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

    end

    def update
      @remision = Remision.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @remision.update(remision_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @remision, notice: 'Remision actualizada correctamente.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @remision }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @remision.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def set_remision
      @remision = Remision.find(params[:id])
    end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def remision_params
        params.require(:remision).permit(:fecha_expedicion,:fecha_vencimiento,:clienteremi_id,:nota,:valor_bruto,:descuento,:subtotal,:iva,:total,
        atriremis_attributes: [:id,:referencia, :descripcion, :lote, :iva, :cantidad, :unidad, :valor_unitario, :valor_total, :_destroy])
      end

end
```

show

```
<div  class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
  <center>
    <h1>Detalles del registro</h1>
  </center>
</div>
<center>



<p>
  <strong>Fecha Expedicion:</strong>
  <%= @remision.fecha_expedicion %>
  <strong>Fecha Vencimiento:</strong>
  <%= @remision.fecha_vencimiento %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Cliente :</strong>
  <%=@remision.clienteremi.nombre %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>Apellidos :</strong><%=@remision.clienteremi.apellidos%>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Empresa :</strong><%=@remision.clienteremi.empresa%>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Nit :</strong><%=@remision.clienteremi.nit%>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Ciudad :</strong><%=@remision.clienteremi.ciudad%></p>



<% @remision.atriremis.each do |atriremi|%>
<p><strong>referencia : </strong><%= atriremi.referencia%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Descripcion :</strong><%=atriremi.descripcion%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Lote :</strong><%=atriremi.lote%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>%IVA :</strong><%=atriremi.iva%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Cantidad :</strong><%=atriremi.cantidad%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Unidad :</strong><%=atriremi.unidad%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Valor unt :</strong><%=atriremi.valor_unitario%>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Valor tol :</strong><%=atriremi.valor_total%></p>
<%end%>

<p>
  <strong>Nota:</strong>
  <%= @remision.nota %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Valor Bruto:</strong>
<%= @remision.valor_bruto %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Descuento:</strong>
  <%= @remision.descuento %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Sub Total:</strong>
  <%= @remision.subtotal %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Iva:</strong>
  <%= @remision.iva %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Total:</strong>
  <%= @remision.total %>
</p>

    <%= link_to 'Editar', edit_remision_path(@remision),class:"btn btn-warning" %>
    <%= link_to 'Atras', remisions_path,class:"btn btn-primary" %>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white ">
        <center>
      <h3>Generar Remision</h3>
      <%= link_to 'PDF',remision_path(@remision, format: "pdf"), class:"btn btn-outline-danger mr-2" %>
      </center>
    </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: El segundo ejemplo debería funcionar; ¿podrías agregar el código completo del modelo y del controlador?

Comment: @Gerry es un modelo creado para un maestro de detalle (son atributos o productos de una remision) con la gema coccon, pero creo que el controlador no ah de importar o si ?

Comment: ¿Cómo utilizas `valor_total` en la vista?

Comment: Normalmente  en el formulario <%= f.input :valor_total%> y el mi show <%=atriremi.valor_total%>

Comment: @Gerry funciona cuando lo defino y lo veo en el modelo de los datos, pero al momento de crear o editar saca error : undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5): ("y me muestra el metodo definido")

Comment: El error se debe a que `self.cantidad` aún no tiene información; ¿en qué controlador recibes y guardas los datos del formulario? Debes asegurarte que hayan sido asignados los atributos `cantidad` y `valor_unitario`  en la instancia del modelo _**antes**_ de llamar al método `valor_total`.

Comment: Los guardo en el controlador de remisiones, entonces como lo deberia hacer ? probe dandole valores por defecto en la vista con=  :input_html => { :value => 0 } , pero no funciona.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el controlador de remisiones y la vista completa?

Comment: @Gerry anexo controller y show de remisiones

Comment: No logro encontrar el problema en tu código; ¿los logs te muestran algún error al mostrar la vista?, ¿cuál es el comportamiento al probar la misma remisión en la consola de rails?

Comment: No ninguno, solo muestra lo mismo que en la pagina, el mismo error

Comment: Probablemente el error provenga de alguna otra vista; si quieres sube tu proyecto a Gtihub y comparte la liga, para poder ver todo el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en la forma hay conflicto al momento de llamar al método `valor_total` ya que, además del método, el modelo tiene una columna con el mismo nombre. Desconozco la razón (tendría que ver la implementación de la forma en el código de Rails) por la que genera error al realizar la operación, pero tienes un par de opciones para no lidiar con el error:

1. Eliminar `valor_total` de la forma, finalmente es un valor que no debería ser capturado (propenso a errores); es mejor que lo calcules y guardes el registro con el valor calculado, por ejemplo, utilizando un *callback*:

   ```
   class Atriremi < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :remision

     before_save :calcula_valor_total

     private
     def calcula_valor_total
       self[:valor_total] = cantidad * valor_unitario
     end
   end
   ```
2. Eliminar `valor_total` de la forma y del modelo, dejando el método `valor_total` definido, así se calcularía dicho valor cada vez que se muestre en alguna vista; tu modelo quedaría tal como lo muestras en la pregunta<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   class Atriremi < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :remision

     def valor_total
       cantidad * valor_unitario
     end
   end
   ```

   <sup><sup>1</sup>*El uso de `self` no es necesario cuando haces operaciones de lectura sobre los atributos.*</sup>

En ambos casos se sugiere eliminar la opción `valor_total` de la forma, pero si deseas conservarla, entonces no deberías realizar el cálculo con el código, ya que estás dando esa responsabilidad al usuario.

Comment: perfecto funciona, ahora tengo otro dilema que es el que comente anteriormente, ahora darle valor a valor_bruto que hace parte de remisiones, valor bruto seria igual a la suma de  todos los valores_totales, no se como hacerlo

Comment: @STIVENARTEAGAESPITIA Súper! Si funciona, por favor acepta la respuesta (dando clic en la paloma) y abre una nueva pregunta para poder responderte sin que la respuesta actual pierda sentido o se extienda demasiado (el sitio funciona mejor haciendo 1 pregunta por _post_; date una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para más información sobre el funcionamiento del sitio).